# How to check string length range in a short form in java?

Tags: java

How to check string range in a short  from in java?

```
if( !(str2.length() >= 3) && !(str2.length() <= 15)){
    System.out.println("Minumum length required");
}
```

rather than using like above. is there any short??

Comment: Please define what you mean by short.

Comment: Your code still doesn't do what you think it does.  Perhaps you meant to write `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Looks fine for me. There's no `in between` or something.

Comment: You could write `if (str2.length() < 3 || str2.length() > 15 ) {` but there's not too much point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to optimisation of working code.  It could go on codereview.stackexchange.com for example.

Comment: @DavidWallace This question would be off-topic on Code Review, because it contains broken code. It would also be a poor Code Review question because it lacks context — we would want to understand what else is being validated so that we can give appropriate advice.

Comment: @DavidWallace , I do believe this is a bug.  Name a length that makes this true.

Comment: Yes, there's certainly a bug in the code.  But the question isn't about the bug.  It's about whether there's a shorter way to do a "between" comparison.  And that's a codereview.SE question, not a SO question.

Comment: @DavidWallace Code with bugs in it is going to be closed as off-topic on [codereview.se], no matter the user's question--so don't recommend questions with bugs to [codereview.se].  Moreover, just so you understand, a question where the user's only question is how to make their already short code "shorter" is likely to be extraordinarily poorly received on [codereview.se].  A question that starts off so small and asks for a fewer-character solution will probably be closed on [codereview.se] as a Code Golf request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(!(str2.length() >= 3) && !(str2.length() <= 15))`

is the same as

`( (str2.length() < 3) && (str2.length() > 15))`

is the same as

`(str2.length() < 3) && (15 < str2.length())`

which is always false.

There is no number that is both less than 3 and greater than 15.

So these are pointless comparisons.

If you want to know that length is between 3 and 15, inclusive, use

`if (3 <= str2.length() && str2.length() <= 15)`

It's easy on the eyes and reminds people of familiar math expressions like 3 ≤ x ≤ 15.

But if that's what you meant your message needs fixing as well.  If you meant what you said then the shortest version of this code is a blank line.  It'll do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not shorter but at least correct

```
if (!(str2.length() >= 3 && str2.length() <= 15)){
    System.out.println("text length is not within range");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local variable.

```
int len = str2.length();
if (len < 3 || len > 15)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("String length" + len + " out of range.");
```

You could use a single comparison but this is not shorter.

```
if (len + Integer.MIN_VALUE - 3 > Integer.MIN_VALUE - 3 + 15)
```

This works as values below 3 will underflow and appear to be very large.